# android - HTML in String resource

Tags: android, android-xml

I'm trying to justify text by using a `WebView` and formatting a String resource with HTML as saw in some example:

```
     <string name="dTxt">
    <html>
        <head></head>
        <bodystyle text-align:justify=""><body> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur  adipiscing elit. 
   Nunc pellentesque, urna nec hendrerit pellentesque, risus massa </body>
   </bodystyle>
   </html>
   </string>
```

ADT refuses to parse the Strings document with following error:

```
  W/ResourceType( 2612): Bad XML block: header size 296 or total size 6144712 is larger than data size 0
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: < and > are forbidden characters in xml. you need to encode them (or put the html file in your raw folder rather than as a string)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

njzk2 is right, < and > are forbidden to use them directly as string. However, you can wrap the HTML in CDATA:

```
<string name="dTxt">
<![CDATA[
    <html>
        <head></head>
        <bodystyle text-align:justify="">
            <body> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur  adipiscing elit. 
                Nunc pellentesque, urna nec hendrerit pellentesque, risus massa 
            </body>
        </bodystyle>
   </html>
]]>
</string>
```

Answer (score 1):

try 
these string Resource with `Html.fromHtml(source)` inside your java code

Comment: it won't work. The string resource has a wrong syntax. You need to use CDATA block

Comment: @marqss thanks for comment ! can you please point out which wrong syntax ?

Comment: The code in the question has incorrect syntax. String resource cannot contain < and > chars directly unless you encode them. However, easier and more efficient way is to wrap the whole HTML in the CDATA block - see my answer

Comment: @marqss i am following http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html

Comment: Html.fromHtml(source) returns Spanned text which can be used in TextViews not WebViews. Spanned supports only some of the HTML tags and omits CSS.